# How to choose the type of PvP battle?

Tags: star-conflict

How to choose the type of PvP battle? Or it is just random? I need it to pass mission which can be only don in "Combat Recon" mode

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always random, you can select game modes via custom battles, but I don't think quests are completable within them.

As you gain Tiers (3 ranks = 1 tier) more and more game types are introduced. So by Tier 5 you have all of them. Within Tier 1 and 2 there are limited game modes, so Combat Recon might not be available until Tier 3.

I know for sure it's in Tier 3, might be there in 2.

```
*Tier 1 - Rank 1 - 3
*Tier 2 - Rank 4 - 6
*Tier 3 - Rank 7 - 9
*Tier 4 - Rank 10 - 12
*Tier 5 - Rank 13 - 15
```